# IllegalStateException Already value ReactiveNeo4JTransactionHolder for key InternalDriver bound to context

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Neo4J 4.x with Spring Data, I have multiple reactive repositories.

I have a function that returns a Mono as:

```
return carsRepositories.findByd(id).flatmap(car -> wheelRepository.save(wheelNode)).then();
```

I get an error **`IllegalStateException Already value ReactiveNeo4JTransactionHolder for key InternalDriver bound to context`**.

I can `findById` or save the `wheelNode` independently, but when I chain them together, I run into that transactional problem.

Note: In my `flatmap` I want to set the relationship `wheel->car`, but I omitted that part.

Comment: The Java statement provided is not well formed (unmatched parentheses).

Comment: Also, can you provide the exception's stacktrace?

Comment: Fixed the parentheses, the full stack trace is all internal on Reactor, I cannot copy-paste as I have the code on a disconnected computer, I will try to give more insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working.

I removed bidirectional relationships in the graph and that solved my issue, I guess that Neo4J didn't like Car pointing to Wheel and Wheel pointing to Car.

Comment: Interesting. Yes, 1:1 [bidirectional relationships is an anti-pattern](https://graphaware.com/blog/neo4j/neo4j-bidirectional-relationships.html). You can just as easily and efficiently traverse a relationship in the reverse direction.